# F-1 alien on OPT in the US transitioning into H1-B; do I have a road to credit?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit

I came to the United States on an F-1 Student Visa, and despite trying here and there, I haven't been approved for any credit in America.

I have a fairly sizeable amount of credit under my name (and further credit for corporations in which I have major stakes) in my country of citizenship.

Not having credit available is inconvenient, since I wind up having to pay deposits or being turned down for services like telecommunications and rent. While day to day purchases aren't a problem (I have a US Dollar credit card issued by my country of citizenship), I feel that I'd much rather just have an American credit card if only to build up my credit history here.

So what should I do to go about it, or is it even a worthy cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple.

Go to the bank of your fancy, give them $1000 as a deposit, and get a Secured Credit Card with the credit limit of $1000. It will be reported to all the credit agencies as a full blown revolving credit line, and you'll start accumulating your credit rating.

After a while (approximately a year) you will start receiving offers for non-secured credit cards, and the one you've got will be converted to a non-secured and your deposit will be refunded to you.

Of course, you have to pay in time, and keep your credit utilization at no more than 30% for the best results.

It is a worthy cause because staying in the US for prolong period of time will require credit history (for rentals, utilities, cell phone services, car leases, and what else). You can live without it, but it will be an inconvenience, as you have already noticed.